# Cauchy convergence question: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Can anyone provide a hint as to how I can prove the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$, [sequence c in the attached question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcGn4.jpg), is Cauchy? This is from Russell A. Gordon's real analysis: a First Course.

The reason I believe this has to be done through Cauchy convergence is because it is from the same section in the book (Cauchy convergence and bounded monotone convergence) and parts a and b are somewhat easily proven to be Cauchy convergent. It also has an oscillatory behavior. Obviously series tests are not applicable either for the same reason, i.e., not encountered yet in the book.

I'm unable to figure out how I can reduce $$\left |x_n-x_m \right |=\left |\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right |$$ to a tractable greater series to be summed, e.g., through the telescopic formula, as in (likely) parts a and b, or any other convergent series.

Comment: **Hint :** $$\left |\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right | \leq \dfrac{1}{m+1}$$

Comment: Yes. Thank you. My apologies for asking a previously answered question. I googled and nothing showed up.

Comment: @FredUlman google is good, but you can also search the toolbar at the top of this webpage, and also https://approach0.xyz/search/ .

Comment: I will in the future. Thanks.